# import { Dialogs } from "@nativescript/core"; is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need to use **Dialogs** for my project. But by importing it from **@nativescript/core** (according to their docs) is not accepted. Showing error: **Module '"@nativescript/core"' has no exported member 'Dialogs'.ts(2305).**
I couldn't find a suitable solution. Please help.
(Nativescript Angular)

Comment: You have not even show most important part. Your code for import.

Answer (score 0):

you can import using following:

`import * as dialogs from "@nativescript/core/ui/dialogs";`